# Unexpected unqualified-id's and initializers before

Tags: c++

I get error messages saying `expected unqualified id or initializers` and im clueless. it was working before, same code, but not anymore.

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Bank
{
    public:
       Bank();
       void setaccount(string a){ //unqualified id before {
          account = a;
       }
    }
    string getaccount() { // expected initializer before getaccount
        return account;
    }

private:                  // unqualified id before private
    string account;


}; // expected declaration 

#endif // MYCLASS_
```

Comment: fixed formatting and made the error quite visible

Answer (score 0):

You're using `std::string`, but haven't included the header for it.  Add

```
#include <string>
```

to your file.

And get rid of `using namespace std;`, as it is [considered bad practice](/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).